# Local Dynamodb: create tables, keys and indexes

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, testing, amazon-dynamodb

I would like to use a Java Spring Boot microservice with DynamodDB as database.

In order to run the unit/integration tests or for development profile I would like to use a local (dockerized) Dynamodb database.

I found this DynamoDB docker image:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.DownloadingAndRunning.html#docker

Now the question is: how can I create the tables/indexes etc into my DynamoDb local instance.

I would like to set-up it automatically (without any manual procedure). Can you suggest an approach?

Answer (score 0):

Im unsure what you mean by set-up automatically without manual procedure?

In essence, the API for DynamoDB Local is exactly the same as DynamoDB Web API. To create a table you will need to call [`CreateTable`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_CreateTable.html) using the [SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/developer/tools/) of your choice.

Typically when I want to create things locally, I use the AWS CLI. Here is how I would create a table locally, pay attention to the `--endpoint-url` this is the only differentiator between Local and Web DynamoDB:

```
aws dynamodb create-table \
    --table-name MusicCollection \
    --attribute-definitions AttributeName=pk,AttributeType=S AttributeName=sk,AttributeType=S \
    --key-schema AttributeName=pk,KeyType=HASH AttributeName=sk,KeyType=RANGE \
    --provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=5,WriteCapacityUnits=5 \
    --tags Key=Owner,Value=blueTeam \
    --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

DynamoDB Local removed its front-end shell in favor of [DynamoDB NoSQL Workbench](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/workbench.html) which you can use to create/edit tables and index and deploy locally.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/nosql-workbench-for-amazon-dynamodb-adds-support-for-dynamodb-local/